# MathJax in Android WebView - injecting the script after the HTML page is loaded

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, mathjax

I have to add MathJax functionality to my app.

According to some examples the correct script to be added is

```
<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                            +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
                           + "showMathMenu: false, "
                           + "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], "
                           + "showProcessingMessages: false, "
                           + "messageStyle: 'none', "
                           + "extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], "
                           + "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                           + "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] } "
                           + "});</script>"
                           + "<script type='text/javascript' "
                           + "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/es5/tex-mml-svg.js'"
                           + "></script><span id='math'></span>
```

The script is loaded from local folder inside the Asset directory.

I have to add that script to a local HTML file when loaded in the Android WebView from another folder on the filesystem (private app folder).

The HTML page has math formulas inside that have to be read by the MathJax functions.

I cannot inject the script as a tag in the HTML file before loading. But also the rendering of the formulas have to be performed immediately after loading.

In the examples they suggest something like:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                        +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
                       + "showMathMenu: false, "
                       + "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], "
                       + "showProcessingMessages: false, "
                       + "messageStyle: 'none', "
                       + "extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], "
                       + "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                       + "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] } "
                       + "});</script>"
                       + "<script type='text/javascript' "
                       + "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/es5/tex-mml-svg.js'"
                       + "></script><span id='math'></span>","text/html","utf-8","");
```

That instruction is executed after the page is loaded, followed by

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
```

that I think is the instruction to render all the math tags in the document

but I get

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined"
```

What is the correct way to inject the script in the loaded page and perform the rendering?

Comment: Have you already tried this?
        String js_command = "(function() { MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]); })();";
        page.evaluateJavascript(js_command, new ValueCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "result: " + result);
            }
        });

Comment: @TomInCode I get the same error with your variant (I get null in the callback). Furthermore, I think that using loadUrl for the main script alters the body. Indeed in some parts of the code the body is selected as a node in a range (for reason I cannot explain here), but that yields this error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'". This is why I think that loadUrl is messing with the HTML page itself instead of adding the script.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for my case was the following code

```
String scriptText=
                        "MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
                        + "showMathMenu: false, "
                        + "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], "
                        + "showProcessingMessages: false, "
                        + "messageStyle: 'none', "
                        + "extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], "
                        + "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                        + "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] } "
                        + "});";

                
String js_command = "var newScript = document.createElement(\"script\");"
+"newScript.setAttribute('type','text/x-mathjax-config');"
+"var inlineScript = document.createTextNode(\""+scriptText+"\");"
+"newScript.appendChild(inlineScript);"
+"document.body.appendChild(newScript);"

+"newScript = document.createElement(\"script\");"
+"newScript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');"
+"newScript.setAttribute('src','file:///android_asset/MathJax/es5/tex-mml-svg.js');"
+"document.body.appendChild(newScript);";
```

without the subsequent calling instruction

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);
```

The code is called this way:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(js_command);
```

After some seconds the script works and the rendering is done, that is, the formulas appear as real math expressions (with right font, layout, and so on).